# Browser behavior with huge doms

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, web-applications, cpu-usage

Can anyone speak to how the different browsers handle the following:

Picture an HTML document essentially rendering content of a static app with lots of data.

```
<div class="abundant_class">
    <div class="abundant_class">
        <div class="abundant_class"></div>
        <div class="abundant_class"></div>
        ...
    </div>       
    <div class="abundant_class">...</div>
    <div class="abundant_class">...</div>
    ...
</div>
```

Imagine O(1000) such elements in the document.

What's the fastest way to assign a click event to all of these elements?

- `<div class="abundant_class" onclick="javascript:foo()">`
- `$('.abundant_class').click(function(foo();));`
- `$('div').click(function(){if ($(this).hasClass('abundant_class')){foo();}`
- something else?

I'm wondering specifically how much memory and CPU these choices incur.

Thanks in advance.

Trevor Mills

Answer (score 4):

In cases like this use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), where you shift the load from initial binding to event bubbling (which happens anyway), like this:

```
$('div.abundant_class').live('click', function() {
  foo();
});
```

This binds *one* event handler to `document` and listens for the `click` event to [bubble up](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) and acts upon that, if the element the event bubbled from matches the selector.

As per the comment discussion, here's the *very* optimized version:

```
$(document.body).delegate('div.abundant_class', 'click', function() {
  foo();
});
```

Comment: Even better is `$('body').delegate('div.abundant_class', 'click', function() { ... })` because there's no need to build the jQuery object for all those divs.

Comment: @Pointy - Even better is `document.body`, but on both points you're getting into micro-optimizing IMO :) Also you can bind a `.live()` handler in the `<head>` even, *outside* a `document.ready` handler, the DOM need not be ready for a `.live()` handler (where `<body>` would need to be), you can attach a `.live()` event handler at a point it'll select no elements that match it ;)

Comment: Well sure, but if he's bothering at all, there's no reason not to avoid traversing all the `<div>` elements. Also `$('body')` is pretty well short-circuited. In my opinion the "live" function should really have always worked the way "delegate" does. *edit* - ok yes all that's true, but it still seems easier to just use "delegate".

Comment: I agree, the interface for `live()` is basically broken (and obviously won't work properly if the wrapper it's used on was obtained by means other than a simple selector). I prefer `delegate` for this reason as well as the practical issue with unnecessary selector resolution.

Comment: @Pointy - Definitely a valid point, added the `.delegate()` option as well, @bobince - That may be changing, there's a ticket on the table for it IIRC.